# How can I print out list of drop down menu using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to print out all the item in the first drop-down menu in this page (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) with Selenium Python and its PhantomJS function. But it still returns No Attribute error message.

Please help.

My code snippet is like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

link = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(link)
sleep(.75)

s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')

# open maker layer
next_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="제조사 선택"]')
next_elem.click()

# print maker
next_elem = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
print ("clicked maker", next_elem.text)
sleep(.75)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next_elem` contains *a list of elements* (because you've used `find_elements_by_tag_name()` method - note the "s") which does not have a `.text` attribute.

You can quickly fix it by using `find_element_by_tag_name()` to match a single element:

```
next_elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('li')
```

But, I think, you probably meant to get the list of makers which can be accessed via:

```
makers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#layer_maker ul.list li a")
for maker in makers:
    print(maker.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, alecxe. That is what I exactly meant. I deeply appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.